# How to select all text of a TextBox on mouse click? (TextBox.SelectAll() not working on TextBox.Enter)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, textbox, controls

I have a `TextBox` and I want all the text inside of it to be highlighted when the user clicks on it (so that they can replace it easily). I have the following event handler linked up the the `TextBox`:

```
private void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SelectAll();
}
```

When I click on the `TextBox`, the text is only selected for a fraction of a second (sometime it's so fast I can't see it at all) and then it goes back to being a cursor. Does anyone know how to fix this or if there are any relatively simple workarounds?

I tried the same thing with the `TextBox.MouseClick` event (and it highlighted the text), but because it was the `MouseClick` event the text was highlighted every time I clicked the `TextBox` (even when the `TextBox` already had focus).

I have also tried `SelectionStart = 0; SelectionLength = Text.Length`, but the same thing happens. This leads me be believe the issue has something to do with the event.

I also tried the `TextBox.GotFocus` event and had the exact same problem.

I am doing this in a Windows Form application.

Comment: What is the definition of `SelectAll()`?

Comment: @maccettura "Selects all the text in the text box."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason why you didn't see the text getting selected is that the `TextBox` is busy when one of those events occurs (e.g., caret positioning). You actually select the text, but then the internal event handlers of the `TextBox` execute and remove the selection e.g. by setting the caret position.

All you have to do is to wait until the internal event handlers have completed.
You do this by using the `Dispatcher`. When you invoke the `Dispatcher` asynchronously the delegate is not immediately executed but enqueued and executed once all previously enqueued actions (like the internal event handlers) are cleared from the dispatcher queue.

So going with the `TextBox.GotFocus` event in WPF (or the `TextBox.Enter` in WinForms) and the asynchronous `Dispatcher` will do the trick:

**WPF**

```
private async void SelectAll_OnTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var textBox = sender as TextBox;
  await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(textBox.SelectAll, DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

**WinForms**

```
private void SelectAll_OnTextBoxEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var textBox = sender as TextBox;
  textBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(textBox.SelectAll));
}
```

Comment: Are you writing a WinForms application?

Comment: You also tagged it WPF. My current answer is targeting WPF. Let me add the corresponding WinForms solution. Hold on.

Comment: I've added a WinForms example.

Comment: Yes sorry didn't validated it. Was a copy & paste remainder from the previous WPF example. I also updated the delegate of the `textBox.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Yep, came to that conclusion too. With the edit it works like a charm.

Comment: Last remark. As I assumed you were using WPF at first, I recommended to use the `GotFocus` event. Since you are using WinForms [Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) to use the `Enter` event instead. In WinForms the `GotFocus` will also work but should only be used when listening to a custom control. When listening to a `Form` use the `Form.Activated` event.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! This makes sense now... I was struggling getting my text properly focus after mouse click, you saved me.

Comment: @IFrank I'm glad you found this post helpful. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Just tested. This works

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully I found a solution! It turns out that the `Click` event is executed before the `Enter` event, this allowed me to set up a `JustGotFocus` variable and do the following:

```
private void myTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    this.JustGotFocus = true;

    if (JustGotFocus) {
        myTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
}

private void myTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    JustGotFocus = false;
}
```

If anyone else has this problem hopefully my solution is useful.

Comment: What is wrong with the `GotFocus` event? This is what you need.

Comment: Check my answer. You don't need that extra logic with checking a flag and using two events. This is too much code for this simple task.

Comment: @BionicCode GotFocus was deprecated in favor of the Enter event.